# Cmake target_link_libraries producing multiple linking problems

Tags: cmake

I porting a big qmake project to cmake and I have multiple linking problems, LNK2001, LNK2019 like:

foo.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: signed char __cdecl libA::XXX::YYY(void)const "
(?YYY@XXX@libA@@QEBACXZ)

foo.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: unsigned short __cdecl libA::XXX::YYY(void)const " (?YYY@XXX@libA@@QEBAGXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl libA::ZZZZ(class LibA::WWWW &)" (?ZZZZ@libA@@YAXAEAVVVVV@1@@Z)

I think that the main problem is that I have libraries that are used in the main project as well in other libraries. But I don't discard the fact that in target_include_directories I'm adding a folder with the same name.

Example of my structure:

Project (Main):

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS core REQUIRED)
add_executable(main...
target_include_directories(main...
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC
    Qt5::Core
    libA
    libB
)
```

Project (LibA):

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS core REQUIRED)
add_library(libA...
target_include_directories(libA PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC
    Qt5::Core
    libB
    libC
)
```

Project (LibB):

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS core REQUIRED)
add_library(libB...
target_include_directories(libB PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_link_libraries(libB PUBLIC
    Qt5::Core
    libA
)
```

Project (LibC):

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS core REQUIRED)
add_library(libC...
target_include_directories(libC PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_link_libraries(libC PUBLIC
    Qt5::Core
    libA
    libB
)
```

I'm missing something or doing something not properly??

Comment: Please, add to the question post the **exact error message**. This is a requirement of Stack Overflow. If there are many error messages generated for your project, then make sure to provide at least the first of them.

Comment: Sorry I added a couple of my multiple errors

Comment: The error message notes the file `foo.cpp`. Which library (executable) this file belongs to? The error message notes the function `libA::XXX::YYY`. Which file **defines** this function and to which library (executable) this file belongs? Please, update the question post to include all relevant information about the problem. And instead of "abstract" code and errors prepare **concrete** [mcve].